# storing facebook javascript functions in a file and using them

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I am writing a code to login the user through the facebook. I store all the function in a file along with other javascript function. I try calling login function from another javascript function and get following error: login is not defined. Here is the code for index.html

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href = "#" onClick = "sayhi();">Hi!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is javascript.js

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '213443452146381', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : '//http://abc.in/', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') 
    {
    alert('connected');
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    alert('not_authorized');
    login();
    } else {
    alert('chillonly');
    login();
    }
    });

    function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            alert('connected');
            testAPI();
        } else {
           alert('not_connected_login');
           testAPI();
        }
    });
    }
    function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
    }
    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));
// ]]>

function sayhi()
{
alert('Hi');
login();
}
```

I doubt if the facebook jdk is getting loaded at all. Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `login()` is not accessible since it is in a local scope.

If you want `function login() {` to be used outside of that scope, you need to make it global or part of some global namespace.

Change

```
function login() {
```

to

```
window.login = function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, move the functions out of the window.fbAsyncInit. They are not accessible since in the local scope.
2. Then, you can have a flag that will only set to true when the JS-SDK is loaded, and you can "block" any process outside the **window.fbAsyncInit** till the flag is set. Something like:

   ```
   var isLoaded = false;
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
   {
      isLoaded = true;
      ...
      ... 
   }

   function myFunc(myVar) 
   {
     if(isLoaded) 
     {
     // Do FB related stuff
     }
   }
   ```